# CSS stop rotating element when user scroll

Tags: html, css

I am rotating an element using CSS transform. But what happening is when I scroll transformed content is again rotating. Here is the CSS I am using

```
.child{
  transform: translate(33%) rotateY(-45deg) rotateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.parent{perspective: 1000px;}
```

how to avoid rotating again and when user scroll?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your CSS, I would suspect the issue is happening on your JS script which triggers the .cocoAnimate class to the HTML element, check it if you are listening to scroll but not stoping it after the event fired

Comment: @AugustoM I found that it is happening because of perspective: 1000px; which parent element has. But i don't know how to stop it

Comment: You should post more code to have this reviewed, you changed your previous code